# load selected columns of table in Dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark

Is there any way I could query on table to select limited columns and load in Dataset. Dont want to load everything then filter the columns.

This can  be done at `UDF` level, but is there any other way using spark funtion where I could write customized query to get data from table then load.

Not able to write this implementation in spark java program. Can anyone share any small example ? looked online but couldnt find this kind of example.

Comment: What database are we talking about? The JDBC connector allows for an SQL query to be specified in the reader's options. But there is nothing wrong in loading all columns and selecting a subset afterwards. It will anyway end up in a limited DB query upon execution after Catalyst does its optimisation magic.

Comment: Its oracle. Can you please share any sample code of doing it ? and secondly, Does Catalyst optimizer drops to <not required> columns from memory ? If yes, then how it decides to drop ?

Comment: Spark queries are lazily evaluated. If you have a dataset `df` that has all the columns of a table and you do `df.select("a").count()`, Spark will issue an SQL query that only selects the `a` column and will not load any of the rest of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can select a database table as follows

```
val df = spark
  .read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", db2JdbcUrl)
  .option("dbtable", myTable)
  .load()
```

but in your case you could do something like this:

```
val selectStatement = "(select name,age from person)a"
val df = spark
  .read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", db2JdbcUrl)
  .option("dbtable", selectStatement)
  .load()
```